# rounding up decimal to next number in php

Tags: php, decimal

I am looking to round up any decimal number to next number. like **1.199** 
 answer should be **2** or like **1.99** should also be **2**

This is far what I found

```
echo(round(1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "<br>");
echo(round(-1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . "<br>");
//Answer = 1
//Answer = -1

echo(round(1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "<br>");
echo(round(-1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "<br>");
//Answer = 1
//Answer = -1

echo(round(1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
echo(round(-1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
//Answer = 1
//Answer = -1

echo(round(1.4,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) . "<br>");
echo(round(-1.,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD));
//Answer = 1
//Answer = -1
```

Comment: So `1.01` should also be 2?

Comment: Use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

```
echo ceil(1.9999);  // 2
echo ceil(1.001);   // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to next up number use `ceil`

```
echo ceil(1.99); //Output = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
echo ceil(1.9999);  // Output will be 2
```

For more detail please refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_ceil.asp